# Can't display price through RevenueCat by using Ionic capacitor

Tags: typescript, capacitor, revenuecat

I am trying to use RevenueCat to do In App Purchases with my Ionic React app by using typescript and capacitor. I have this following code in my Ionic app:

```
  const purchases = async () => {
        try {
            const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
            if (offerings.current !== null && offerings.current.availablePackages.length !== 0) {
                console.log("OFFERING");
                console.log(offerings.current.monthly);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
```

...

```
return (
     <IonButton onClick={purchases}>Monthly Subscription</IonButton>
)
```

I have got this error: cordova_not_available

I have read of [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community#react) and knowing that React apps must use Capacitor to build native mobile apps. However, Ionic Native (and therefore, Cordova plugins) can still be used. So I did all the install plugin/packages in the article, however, it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution to your issue since it's a bit old.

Otherwise, I have made a Capacitor plugin who handles subscription thanks to the fabulous RevenueCat SDK.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/Cap-go/capacitor-purchases

It's the same usage as you do in your code, just change the import to:
`@capgo/capacitor-purchases`